# C# Class for XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

First time, long time.

I'm trying to write a C# class that when serialized, will form this SOAP XML string:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                                        <soap:Header>
                                            <wsse:Security>
                                            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                                <wsse:Username>XXXXXX</wsse:Username>
                                                <wsse:Password>XXXXXX</wsse:Password>
                                            </wsse:UsernameToken>
                                            </wsse:Security>
                                        </soap:Header>
                                       <soap:Body><Request xmlns="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/"><corpName>XXXXXX</corpName><userName>XXXXXX</userName><loId>XXXXXX</loId></Request></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I used xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net to generate the following classes but I don't quite understand what if any modifications to the classes need to be made and how to test whether the objects will serialize to the correct format.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="UsernameToken", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class UsernameToken {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Username", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Password", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="wsse", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Wsse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Security", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class Security {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="UsernameToken", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Header", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Header {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Security", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public Security Security { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Request", Namespace="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/")]
public class Request {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="corpName", Namespace="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/")]
    public string CorpName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="userName", Namespace="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="loId", Namespace="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/")]
    public string LoId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Request", Namespace="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/LO/")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Header", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="soap", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soap { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsd", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="wsa", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Wsa { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="wsse", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Wsse { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="wsu", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Wsu { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using the following code but it's not working:

```
Envelope env = new Envelope();

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, env);
        Console.WriteLine(textWriter.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added two classes like

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Request")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

You need to initialize your Envelope like below

```
    Envelope env = new Envelope
    {
        Header = new Header
        {
            Security = new Security
            {
                UsernameToken = new UsernameToken
                {
                    Username = "abcd",
                    Password = "xyz"
                }
            }
        },
        Body = new Body
        {
            Request = new Request
            {
                CorpName = "qw",
                UserName = "df",
                LoId = "gh"
            }
        }
    };
```